# Bash command to convert varying fields from hex to decimal

Tags: bash, text

I have a text file with the sample lines below:

```
40,1,1a,0002,0001,,1234;5678;,027e;0280;
50,1,1a,0001,0004,,,0890;
```

I want to convert items separated by comma or semicolon from hex to decimal but only for the fields to the right of the 2nd field. First and second fields from the left are already in decimal. The number of field varies.

I want to write a command in bash to convert above file to below:

```
40,1,26,2,1,,4660;22136;,638;640;
50,1,26,1,4,,,2192;
```

How can I achieve this? I tried searching for an answer for some time but I really couldn't find the one that works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Noted @Cyrus, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using awk. The tricky part is to split using both commas and semicolon. The easiest is to first split using the commas and then check if there are any semicolons in the resulting substrings

```
echo "40,1,1a,0002,0001,,1234;5678;,027e;0280;" | awk --non-decimal-data -F, '
{printf ("%s,%s,",$1,$2)};
{ for(i = 3; i <= NF; i++) {
  n = split($i,tmp,";")
  { for(j = 1; j <= (n-1); j++)
    if (length(tmp[j]) != 0) {printf ("%d;","0x"tmp[j])} 
  }
  if (length(tmp[j]) != 0) {printf ("%d","0x"tmp[n])} 
  if (i != NF) {printf (",")}
}
{printf ("\n")}
}'

40,1,26,2,1,,4660;22136;,638;640;
```

indicates that the values are not decimal with `--non-decimal-data`

separate the fields on the commas with `-F,`

Print the first 2 values

`{printf ("%s,%s,",$1,$2)};`

Iterate through the substrings, starting with the 3rd field, between the commas:

`for(i = 3; i <= NF; i++)`

Split the substring using the semicolon field, and store the array in the tmp array:

`n = split($i,tmp,";")`

Iterate through the substring and convert the hex into decimal. If the value is missing do not print anything (otherwise it prints 0)

`{ for(j = 1; j <= (n-1); j++)
    if (length(tmp[j]) != 0) {printf ("%d;","0x"tmp[j])} 
 }`

Print the last value without the semicolon

`if (length(tmp[j]) != 0) {printf ("%d","0x"tmp[n])}`

If this is not the last field, add the commas as separator:

`if (i != NF) {printf (",")}`

Comment: It would have been nice if you had waited for kiki's feedback before you answered.

Comment: Thanks @Pierrick! I had awk -F'[,;]' '{ for(i=3; i<=NF; ++i); do echo $((16#$i)); done }'. Your command works perfectly and thanks so much for the detailed explanation!